# Inheriting Model from parent Route

Tags: ember.js

I have an app route that takes an app id, from here I goto app/:app_id/settings, this opens a Twitter Bootstrap modal, from a separate template, from here I'd like to be able to do things like change the app name and other stuff like that but I can't seem to get access to that model. I assumed since I was nesting the routes I would have access to the current app model but I didn't. I also don't have access to the params in the parent route so not sure what to do. I've included the relevant (I think) code below.

```
WEM.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource( 'apps', { path: '/' }, function(){
        this.resource( 'app', { path: 'app/:app_id'}, function(){
            this.resource( 'settings', { path: 'settings' } );
            this.resource( 'error', { path: 'error/:error_id' } );
        });
    });
});

// Routes
WEM.AppsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return WEM.App.find();
    }
});

WEM.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function( params ){
        console.log( WEM.App.find( params.app_id ).get( 'id' ) );
        return WEM.App.find( params.app_id );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think changing the model hook of your `SettingsRoute` to

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor("app");
}
```

might help.

Comment: Is this preferable to using `needs` in the `SettingsController`?

Comment: i think so, but i don't really know.

Comment: I think of them as accomplishing different things.  Needs would give you MORE data than what your model is giving.  If it's truly the same model than this.modelFor() seems fine.